# Doxygen does not create callgraphs

Tags: python, doxygen, call-graph

I am trying to get a callGraph for jython code. My doxygen config contains (among others) these lines:

```
HAVE_DOT = YES
DOT_PATH = /path/to/folder/containing/dot
CALL_GRAPH = YES
CALLER_GRAPH = YES
```

If I look in the generated files I can't find callGraphs or callerGraphs in the function definition, yet I do not get an errrormessage about an issue with dot. All I get are a few errors for undocumented functions, but these should not impede the callgraph output.

Is there anything I am missing? (I would like to avoid using external tools for this like pycallgraph (I run doxygen anyways, and thatway I get the callgraphs in the documentation)

Comment: I had the same problem documenting a project in python using Doxygen. At the end I had to use pylint/pycallgraph to generate inheritance/call graphs.

Comment: @georgesl: not what I hoped to hear, but in the end you might just be right :(. Did you figure out a way to incorporate the callgraph images into the doxygen documentation or did you jsut generate the images as standalone documentation?

Comment: I did only need a handful of inheritance graphs so I used [pyreverse](http://www.logilab.org/6883) to generate my dot files that I included manually into the documentation. Maybe you can automate the process using bash/python script.

Comment: @georgesl: Inheritance graphs work, my boss wanted callgraphs too, those cuase trouble. If youu should document python code with doxygen again give the inbuilt inheritance graphs a shot.